# NullPointerException в AutoCompleteTextView при .setAdapter(adapter);

Tags: android, adapter, autocompletetextview

Нужен `TextView` с автокомплитом в `AlertDialog`.

Создаю разметку для `AlertDialog`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_et_from"
        android:hint="@string/date_from"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_et_to"
        android:hint="@string/date_to"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Инициализирую все это дело в пункте меню:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
    labels.add("text");
    labels.add("test");
    labels.add("abba");
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, labels);
    from = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.dialog_et_from);
    to = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.dialog_et_to);
    from.setAdapter(adapter);
    to.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_choose_range) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setTitle("Заголовок");
        builder.show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

В лог выводит вот это

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at ru.whalemare.weather.activity.ChartActivity.onCreate(ChartActivity.java:139)
```

Где я не прав и как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверно как-то так

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
ayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
from = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_et_from);
to = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_et_to);
from.setAdapter(adapter);
to.setAdapter(adapter);
builder.setView(view);
builder.setTitle("Заголовок");
builder.show();
}
```

Comment: Точно... совсем засиделся уж. Спасибо огромное